# Ignoring a Macro in C in Enterprise Architect C import

Tags: c, import, enterprise-architect

My C code has SECTION annotation used by the linker, for example:

```
static uint32_t SECTION(".bss.My_SECTION") my_data[FP_TAPS_REGION_SIZE / 4u];
```

When I do Code import in EA 14 the parser fails with a syntax error - removing the SECTION solved this.

I tried doing Configure>Settings>Preprocessor Macros - but the select Language only has C++

Suggestions ?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what EA is expected to do with C code anyway.  In particular, note well that C is a separate language from C++, notwithstanding the common subset shared by the two.  In any case, the snippet you present is not standard C without an in-scope definition of a function-like macro named `SECTION`.  I presume that there is no such definition, because I take `SECTION` to be a compiler extension, not a *bona fide* macro.

Comment: What you can do is what you have done: remove the code exercising the extension.  Alternatively, you could be a little more subtle by defining a suitable `SECTION()` macro, presumably with empty replacement text.  If you can somehow do the latter at EA import time then you may be able to use unmodified code, but it remains an open question whether you could successfully round-trip through EA while preserving the `SECTION()` bits.

Comment: For the C compiler, you could `#define SECTION(...)` (with no replacement text) to effectively remove the `SECTION` annotation.  Whether that works with EA is a separate discussion.

Comment: Well, C is not OO and as such no real candidate for UML. You need a human to figure out where it's OO. A machine has difficulties with that.

Comment: Doing a #define SECTION() in the code didn't help... I got the same problem even putting the SECTION on a separate line and foing an #ifdef ir #if didn't help - it looks like EA has an issue with having a macro at that particular position. Sigh...

Comment: @qwerty_so  C is not an OOL  But that doesn't mean that the design is not OO. Nor does it mean that I can't document the code using URL. There is nothing OO about Sequences diagrams and Activity diagrams. EA does a good job of taking a C module, and creating a Class with data (static data), private (static) functions, and public functions

Comment: Yes, a human can recognize the OO structures (even in a COBOL program). But machines have a hard time with that. Not that it would be impossible looking at today's AIs. But then, there is no such AI. Or is there?

Comment: @qwerty_so. Not sure I understand what you are trying to say. All I want is that EA read my C code, and convert each .c file to a class with the private and public functions. It does that well except that the SECTION in the variable definition messes up the parsing - even if I #define it into nothing or a comment. Import of C++  allows you to define macros, but this does not seem to be available for C.

Comment: I wouldn't know what to say except repeating me again. The answer would basically be: `not possible`.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong - you can define the SECTION macro as follows (EA 14)

1. CODE Configure/Options > Define Preprocessor Macros
2. Select Language C++
3. Add New
   etc....

The trick is that by adding it for C++ it also works for C
I was pretty sure I tried this in the past and failed - but it's working now.